# What fields are needed for Google Checkout?

Tags: asp.net, google-checkout

What are the fields to be taken for Google Checkout? Can anybody show me Google Checkout form both in user and admin side?

Comment: How was this not closed as not a real question?

Answer (score 0):

There are various ways of achieving a checkout form, so you'll need to read up on which method will be best for you. Start by reading these explanations by Google which also show you examples of how to achieve them:

http://checkout.google.com/support/sell/bin/answer.py?hl=en-uk&answer=38882

Answer (score 0):

You tagged the question with asp.net, so you may also want to have a look at the Checkout client libraries for .NET and Classic ASP for more info:

http://code.google.com/apis/checkout/samplecode.html